# No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1403)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
... 59 more
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>freemarker</groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml,i have add the the spring.xml in the contextConfigLocation,why still remind me  No qualifying bean of type SessionFactory

```
<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <!-- 此处配置的是SpringMVC的配置文件 -->
        <param-value>classpath:spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/view/login.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cc</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>logintest</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/view/sys/logintest.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>logintest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dd</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring-mvc.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springdemo.*" />

 <mvc:annotation-driven />

 <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/view/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=mysql://localhost:3306/maven?  useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = 123456
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class =     org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path = ehcache.xml
```

UserDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public User findById(Integer id) {

    String ming = "张鹏";


    Session session = null;
    User user = null;
    try {
        session =  getSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        user = new User();
        user.setName(ming);
        user.setAge(25);


        session.save(user);


        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            if (session.isOpen()) {

                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

    return user;
}

}
```

the image is my item directory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7QUS.png)

spring.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springdemo.service,com.springdemo.dao" />
<context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties" />

<!-- ************************MYSql数据源配置开始***************************************************** -->
<!-- C3P0 数据库连接池配置    ; 创建mysql jdbc数据源 -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
     <!--连接关闭时默认将所有未提交的操作回滚。Default: false -->
    <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="true"/>
</bean>



<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>user.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: In UserDaoImpl you are Autowiring SessionFactory bean. can you show us where you define it

Comment: i have add the SessionFactory bean

Comment: you are using org.springframework.orm.hibernate3 in your sessionFactory bean although you are injecting Hibernate 4..

Comment: i have change the org.springframework.orm.hibernate3 to org.springframework.orm.hibernate ,but still the same error